# NFS over TCP not available from x.x.x.x

Tags: nfs, pxe

Ubuntu 21.10

I setup a fully functional PXE server but lately I received an error.

I followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/)

/etc/exports:

```
/netboot/nfs *(rw,sync,no_wdelay,insecure_locks,no_root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

this is Ubuntu 20.04 image
[image: NFS over TCPnot available from ...]

```
label install
menu label Install ^Ubuntu-16.04 Desktop
menu default
kernel ubuntu1604/vmlinuz.efi
append initrd=ubuntu1604/initrd.lz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.4:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu1604/ quiet splash toram


label install
menu label Install Ubuntu-^Desktop-20.04.1LTS
kernel ubuntu2004Desktop/vmlinuz
append initrd=ubuntu2004Desktop/initrd boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.4:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu2004Desktop quiet splash

label install
menu label Install Ubuntu-^Server-20.04.1LTS
kernel ubuntu2004/vmlinuz
append initrd=ubuntu2004/initrd boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.4:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu2004/ quiet splash


 program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  45562  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  50043  mountd
    100005    2   udp  56579  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  52651  mountd
    100005    3   udp  52954  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  55001  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
```

```
Oct 25 18:25:27 zika dnsmasq-tftp[123008]: sent /netboot/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default to 192.168.1.19
Oct 25 18:26:07 zika dnsmasq-tftp[123008]: sent /netboot/tftp/ubuntu2004Desktop/vmlinuz to 192.168.1.19
Oct 25 18:26:23 zika dnsmasq-tftp[123008]: sent /netboot/tftp/ubuntu2004Desktop/initrd to 192.168.1.19
```

and bootchain stop. Why?
I have Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on the same /netboot/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default and 16.04 boots OK. Can anybody have a solution to that?